# Heroku, Keep getting SSL certficate error from Google Web Master Tool

Tags: ssl, heroku

I keep getting ssl certificate error from google web master tool like below.

---

> Dear Webmaster, The host name of your site, https://myapp.com/, does not match any of the "Subject Names" in your SSL certificate, which were:
>   *.herokuapp.com
>   herokuapp.com
>   
>   This will cause many web browsers to block users from accessing your site, or to display a security warning message when your site is accessed. To correct this problem, please get a new SSL certificate by a Certificate Authority (CA) with a "Subject Name" or "Subject Alternative DNS Names" that matches your host name. Thanks, The Google Web Crawling Team

---

I set ssl to my heroku app by following instructions of Heroku dev center.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

I also am using rack_rewrite for 301 redirect for redirecting from naked domain to www subdomain.

It seems everything is going fine from browser, when I access naked domain, it will redirect to https://www.myapp.com without any SSL error.

## output from heroku are like below

```
heroku certs --remote production

Endpoint                Common Name(s)                      Expires               Trusted
----------------------  ----------------------------------  --------------------  -------
XXXXXXXX.herokussl.com  www.myapp.com, myapp.com            2013-08-05 00:20 PHT  True


heroku certs:info --remote production

Fetching information on SSL endpoint XXXXXXX.herokussl.com... done
Certificate details:
    subject: /serialNumber=XXXXXXXXXX www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=www.myapp.com
    start date: (some date)
    expire date: (some date)
    common name(s): www.myapp.com, myapp.com
    issuer: /serialNumber=XXXXXXXXXXX www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)12/OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R)/CN=www.myapp.com
    SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.
```

## domain settings

```
Type    NAME           TTL         Points to
ALIAS   myapp.com      3600     xxxxxx.herokussl.com
CNAME   www.myapp.com  3600     xxxxxx.herokussl.com
```

Why I keep getting the error from Google?

Answer (score 1):

Naked Domains are not supported.  See the documentation section at [Heroku Endpoint SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#naked-domains)

Comment: The Heroku Endpoint SSL documentation doesn't say anything about Naked Domains.  What is a Naked Domain?

Comment: @Sam Backus search for 'root' instead of 'naked' at the link that Cesar provided. Naked just means without a subdomain, in this case. Btw, my guess as to why Atsuhiro was having problems (just a guess) is because it looks like he didn't buy a wildcard SSL, but rather a specific cert just for www.myapp.com, when he should have purchased a wildcard SSL cert for `*.myapp.com` (so that both myapp.com and www.myapp.com would work under SSL). Maybe Atsuhiro will provide us with an update as to how he fixed it, if that wasn't it. Looks like he was correctly using an ALIAS record for his root domain.